# how to test a linear node script with jest?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-node

I am starting a simple script to sign an APK for an Ionic project and I want to to some TDD with it. The problem? I Can not find a way to do this since I do not export any function, I will just do `ts-node my-script`

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to wrap everything in an exported function and then call it from yet another file in order to test it?

As example the structure is until now :

```
import * as colors from 'colors';
import * as prompCreator from 'prompt-sync';

const prompt = prompCreator();

const password = prompt('Sign apk password?: ').trim();

if (!password || password.length === 0) {
  console.error(colors.bgRed.yellow(' You need a password to sign the APK '));
  process.exit(0);
}
```

(after that I decided to write first the spec tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock `prompCreator` and `prompt` methods of `prompt-sync` package and `colors.bgRed.yellow` method.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import colors from 'colors';
import prompCreator from 'prompt-sync';

const prompt = prompCreator();

const password = prompt('Sign apk password?: ').trim();

if (!password || password.length === 0) {
  console.error(colors.bgRed.yellow(' You need a password to sign the APK '));
  process.exit(0);
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import prompCreator from 'prompt-sync';
import colors from 'colors';

jest.mock(
  'colors',
  () => {
    return {
      bgRed: {
        yellow: jest.fn(),
      },
    };
  },
  { virtual: true },
);

jest.mock(
  'prompt-sync',
  () => {
    const mPrompt = jest.fn();
    return jest.fn(() => mPrompt);
  },
  { virtual: true },
);

describe('61950048', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    jest.spyOn(process, 'exit').mockImplementation();
    colors.bgRed.yellow.mockReturnValueOnce('network');
    const errorSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation();
    const mPrompt = prompCreator();
    mPrompt.mockReturnValueOnce('');
    require('./');
    expect(errorSpy).toBeCalledWith('network');
    expect(colors.bgRed.yellow).toBeCalledWith(' You need a password to sign the APK ');
    expect(process.exit).toBeCalledWith(0);
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61950048/index.test.js (9.582s)
  61950048
    ✓ should pass (8ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 8                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.196s
```

Comment: the above solution won't work if there are multiple unit tests requiring the file in a test suite because the file is cached, refer - https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#caching. Use Jest's isolateModules to require a fresh copy of file for each test - https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestisolatemodulesfn